# le 06 de quelqu'un

Tags: sens

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Marseille:

- Je t'envoie le 06 de Mendoza. C'est le directeur.

The English subtitle translation is "I'll send you Mendoza's number. It is the manager" . Is 06 a French area code? Why is it used as synonym of "phone number"?

Answer (score 2):

In France, most of mobile numbers begin with `06`.

> Je t'envoie le 06 de Mendoza.

means:

> I send you Mendoza's mobile number.